# String interpolation to bash inside python code

Tags: python, bash

I need interpolate python variable to bash command something like that:

```
var = foo
cmd = '/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pkitool --server  %s' % var
```

UPDATED: I eronneously posted this question. It seemed to me it doesn't work properly but then I saw code does what it should. Question closed. Anyway it shows people how to interpolate string into bash and thus is useful.

Comment: Maybe you meant `var = "foo"`?

Comment: Better with `cmd = ['/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pkitool', '--server', var]` so you don't need `shell=True` to pick it apart again.

Comment: Does your command require `bash`, or do you just want it executed?

Comment: My code actually does as it should.My excuses.Question closed.@Alex, if you can do not minus me.

Comment: Men,why you minus me? I have no right to make error or you weren't beginners?

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but it is unclear what your problem is and what you have done to resolve it. You can still [edit] your question to rectify these shortcomings; perhaps review the [help] for more information about how to interact with this site first.

Comment: Protip: telling people not to downvote you is a *great* way to inspire them to downvote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have will work if you pass your command as a list to `subprocess.Popen()` or its helper functions such as `subprocess.check_output()`.

You should pass the command as a list for execution:

```
import subprocess

var = 'foo server'
cmd = ['/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pkitool', '--server', var]
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

Comment: Thanks,@mhawke, I know how to run bush under python but your info is useful for me

Comment: This is wrong, or at least misdirected. If there is no shell involved, adding shell quoting will break, not protect, those strings where it actually matters. (It will appear harmless otherwise, but is then also useless.)

Comment: @tripleee: thanks, yeah, you're right - it's both wrong and misdirected. I was concerned about cmd line args containing spaces, but `Popen()` already handles that. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko: just to be clear the code I've shown does not use `bash` or any other shell - it executes the given program directly as a child process. If you want to run `bash` you must include it in the command when setting `shell=False` (the default). Or, if you set `shell=True` the command will be executed with `/bin/sh -c` which might perform differently than would `bash`. You can also affect this with the `executable` `Popen()` parameter.